# How to change the color of a shape/border?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm making Judô diplomas in Word by taking the information in Excel and dropping in the doc.

How would I change the color of a shape/border?

I tried to record my steps but Word seems unable to do it and didn't record anything.

Image below is in Portuguese:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This example recolors all shapes in the active document. You probably need to change the color on one particular shape. Therefore, before changing the color of the lines, you must first select the desired shape, focusing on some signs.

```
Sub ShapesColors()
    Dim doc As Document, sh As Shape
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    For Each sh In doc.Shapes
        With sh.Line
            .Weight = 3
            .ForeColor = vbMagenta
        End With
        sh.Fill.ForeColor = vbWhite
    Next
End Sub
```

Before
[image]

After
[image]